# Why is MSBuild Analyse Code Coverage options disabled in VS2015 Enterprise?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have working unit tests in my solution (separate project generated from Wizard).
I have tried installing a general Test Settings file.
Made sure I am logged in and have a valid Enterprise license under my name.

But my Analyse Code Coverage tool is disabled:

[image: Disabled in both places]

[image: Project structure]

Update: Added screenshot of creating a new project
[image: New Project]

Comment: is it the latest VS2015 version with update 3? Mine is 14.0.25431.01 update 3 version, that option is enabled in my side. If you create a default simple C# Unit test project, how about the result? Please also reset your VS settings. In addition, if you just right click a test method in the test explorer window, do you get the option "Analyze code coverage ..."? Whether it is enabled? If all test methods have the same issue, please check that whether you installed certain extension tools in your VS. Or run VS in safe mode could help you narrow down this issue.

Comment: Yes it is the same version. I have uploaded a screenshot of creating a new project + unit test project and it still having the same problem. If I right click a test method the option is still disabled. Resetting my settings didn't help. I tried safe mode but I get this error in Output: An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsHost.TestWindowHost". and then the Test menu is completely missing. I have checked my extensions and there should be nothing conflicting, I just have things like Xamarin installed.

Comment: Oh no, now my Test menu and tooling has COMPLETELY dissapeared from the IDE. Sigh, what is going on. Trying a repair now and deleting my component cache.

Answer (score 5):

Running a Repair on Visual Studio 2015 and deleting everything in the folder %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache solved this problem, I now have the Test menu back with code coverage enabled and working.

Comment: would you please mark your reply as the answer? So it could help other community members who meet the same issue. Thanks for your sharing:)

Comment: Still works for VS2022